# Search-replace on GUID-tables in WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, guid

My gut-feeling tells me that this is more of a StackOverflow-question, than a WordPress-question, which is why I don't ask it [there](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com).

I'm working on an old site, that hasn't been touched in forever. I can see that there are still quite a few leftovers from the staging environment in the database. So there's a heap of URL's being `http://staging.example.org` instead of `https://example.org`.

So I'm about to do a search-replace on it, - but I'm not sure if I should skip the GUID-tables or not. I'm using the Better Search Replace-plugin, and it has a link to [this page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Important_GUID_Note), which states that I should never-super-duper-ever touch the GUID-column.

But this is not something that once were correct. This is obviously a flaw.

So should I do a search-replace on the GUID-column or not?

Comment: If the official documentation of Wordpress tells you to never ever change that column, why do you want to do it?

Comment: Because it can't be as black'n'white as the documentation suggests. I mean... What if I, the site had been hacked and a bunch of links to viagra-sites had been inserted in the GUID-column. Should I just go on and say: 'Well, that sucks! The documentation clearly states that I shouldn't touch them'. =) ... So I'm wondering where on (a slightly more nuanced) scale of right'n'wrong my specific case is. :-)

Comment: The main purpose of those GUIDs in the WordPress environment is RSS feeds, as far as I can see. If you are not using WP as a blog system and more as a site builder tool, so that RSS feeds are not really relevant, changing them should not matter that much.

Comment: As I assume that your site has not been hacked, there is no need to tamper with the GUID column to avoid distributing such links. After all, if the documentation tells you not to change that column and you have no really good reason to override that rule, what's the point in changing that data?